# Google Checkout API charge-amount-notification

Tags: android-pay

I am getting back the following response from a charge-amount-notification. (in the sandbox env). What I am trying to do is to send an e-mail alert to a customer when I am certain the payment is cleared. Right now I am using new-order-notification and sometimes customers payments will fail and I want to make sure I am delivering the digital download when I get the money.

```
array (
  'charge-amount-notification' => 
  array (
    'xmlns' => 'http://checkout.google.com/schema/2',
    'serial-number' => '962015304346298-00013-2',
    'timestamp' => 
    array (
      'VALUE' => '2012-09-01T13:25:18.732Z',
    ),
    'latest-charge-amount' => 
    array (
      'currency' => 'USD',
      'VALUE' => '99.0',
    ),
    'total-charge-amount' => 
    array (
      'currency' => 'USD',
      'VALUE' => '99.0',
    ),
    'google-order-number' => 
    array (
      'VALUE' => '962015304346298',
    ),
  ),
```

)

I was expecting an order-summary key with customer information as described in documentation.

https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Notification_API#charge_amount_notification

Here is my code:

```
if (isset($_POST['serial-number']))
    {
        require_once('lib/google_checkout/googleresponse.php');
        require_once('lib/google_checkout/googlerequest.php');
        require_once('lib/google_checkout/googlenotificationhistory.php');      
        $response = new GoogleResponse(GOOGLE_MERCHANT_ID, GOOGLE_MERCHANT_KEY);
        $google_notification_history = new GoogleNotificationHistoryRequest(GOOGLE_MERCHANT_ID, GOOGLE_MERCHANT_KEY, GOOGLE_SANDBOX ? 'sandbox' : 'production');
        $raw_xml_array = $google_notification_history->SendNotificationHistoryRequest($_POST['serial-number']);
        $raw_xml = $raw_xml_array[1];
        $response->SendAck($_POST['serial-number'], false);
        list($root, $order_data) = $response->GetParsedXML($raw_xml);

        if (isset($order_data['charge-amount-notification']))
        {
            $data = array();
            file_put_contents("google.txt", var_export($order_data, true));
            $data['name'] = $order_data['charge-amount-notification']['order-summary']['buyer-billing-address']['contact-name']['VALUE'];
            $data['email'] = $order_data['charge-amount-notification']['order-summary']['buyer-billing-address']['email']['VALUE'];
            $data['txn_id'] = $order_data['charge-amount-notification']['google-order-number']['VALUE'];
            $data['payment_status'] = 'Completed';
            $res = save_payment($data);
            if ($res) {
                $data = payment_details(array('txn_id' => $data['txn_id']));
                mail_notification($data);
            }            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<order-summary>` element is included in notifications only with the [2.5 API version](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/release_notes).
The [Google Checkout HTML API Notification API](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_HTML_API_Notification_API) states:

> After establishing your web service, log in to your Merchant Center
>   account, click on the Settings tab and then click on the Integration
>   link in the menu on the left side of the page. Enter the URL for your
>   web service in the API callback URL field. (You need to enter your API
>   callback URL in both your sandbox account and your production
>   account.) You must also indicate the format you wish to receive
>   notifications and the API version. This documentation covers
>   "Notification as Serial Number" and API Version 2.5.

[image]

Comment: It seems 2.5 requires java, is this the case?

Comment: Also what notification should I use when I can guarantee I have received the money?

Comment: Also should I turn on notification filtering?

Comment: @Chris Apologies for my late response, but yesterday, after posting my answer, I turned off my PC and went away, so I've read your comments only now. The answer to your first question is no: the 2.5 API does not require Java. You should turn on notification filtering only if don't want to receive all types of notifications. Since you're interested in the new order notification, you can also turn on notification filtering if you want. I have not understood the question about the type of notification to use when you have received the money. Can you please explain it better?

Comment: I was having an issue where I would get the new order notification and then the payment failed. I already sent them the link to download digital product. What I want to do is NOT send or email them the URL until I am certain they have been charged.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. I think that you should listen for the [authorization-amount-notification](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Notification_API?hl=it#authorization_amount_notification). This notification is sent when the buyer’s credit cart has been authorized, and the buyer has been allowed sufficient time to cancel the order. Once you get this notification, you can ship the goods. Have a look at the [Checkout Processing How To](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_Custom_Processing_How_To) for further details.

Comment: The [charge-amount-notification](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Notification_API?hl=it-IT#charge_amount_notification) is sent only if you use the [charge-and-ship-order](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Financial_Commands?hl=it-IT#Charge_And_Ship_Order) command before the authorization expires. See [this page](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_Custom_Processing_How_To#charge_ship1) for details.